# jQuery Plugin into Ember component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to turn this jQuery plugin https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input into an Ember component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

tagName : "input",
type : "text",
attributeBindings : [ "name", "type", "value", "id"],

_initialize: function() {

    Ember.assert("Tags Input has to exist on Ember.$.fn.tagsInput", typeof Ember.$.fn.tagsInput === "function");

    this.$('#tags').tagsInput({'width':'100px'});

}.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

Then in my handlebar file `{{tag-input id="tags"}}`

But it seems that the jQuery isn't working as it is just a standard input box. This is the generated HTML `<input id="tags" class="ember-view" type="text"></input>`

But if I copy `this.$('#tags').tagsInput({'width':'100px'});` into the console and run it the element uses the plugin.

What would be the reason that the plugin wouldn't get fired on didInsertElement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what [kunerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689033/kunerd) said, you might need to schedule this to after everything is fully rendered by scheduling your code to the `afterRender` queue in the run loop, like this:

```
_initialize: function({
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
    this.$().tagsInput({'width': '100px'});
  });
}).on('didInsertElement')
```

`Ember.run` is a slightly complicated topic, but essentially things happen in order in "queues" that Ember fires off, and the `afterRender` queue is the one that happens after everything is rendered.

Here's [a pretty good blogpost on Ember.run](http://ember.zone/a-50000-foot-overview-of-the-ember-js-run-loop/), and here's [an even more in-depth book-like repository on it](https://github.com/eoinkelly/ember-runloop-handbook).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `this.$("#tags")` searches for a DOM element with id: tags inside your components DOM element.

To solve your problem, you should use `this.$().tagsInput({..})` instead.

Also see [this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fewarujiyu/3/edit) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Add setup jquery code into your component.js like following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

tagName : "input",
type : "text",
attributeBindings : [ "name", "type", "value", "id"],

setupTagsInputPlugin: Ember.on('didRender', function() {
    this.$("#tags").tagsInput({
width:"100px"
    });
  }),

});
```